# TFS build failing because of registry access is not allowed

Tags: tfs, build-automation

I am configuring New bulid server I am having TFS 2013. I am an admin on the build server and the account which is used for configuring build server is also a admin on build server.

I am able to access my TFS and able to Checkin code as well from build server.

I don't know what access rights I have to give to my user or to the account used for configuring build server.

```
Exception Message: Requested registry access is not allowed. (type SecurityException)
Exception Stack Trace: 
Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Internal.TeamFoundationEnvironment.OpenOrCreateRootUserRegistryKey()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workstation.get_AttemptToAutoResolveConflicts()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Client.Get(Workspace workspace, GetRequest[] requests, GetOptions options, GetFilterCallback filterCallback, Object userData, String[] itemAttributeFilters, String[] itemPropertyFilters, Boolean alwaysQueryConflicts, Conflict[]& conflicts, Int32 operationId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Get(GetRequest[] requests, GetOptions options, GetFilterCallback filterCallback, Object userData, String[] itemAttributeFilters, String[] itemPropertyFilters, Boolean alwaysQueryConflicts, Conflict[]& conflicts)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Get(GetRequest[] requests, GetOptions options, GetFilterCallback filterCallback, Object userData)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfGet.TfGetCore.RunCommand(VersionControlScope versionControlScope, Workspace workspace, String getting, String nonFatalError, String version, String fileSpec, GetOptions options, RecursionType recursion)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   at System.Func`9.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfGet.TfGetCore.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
```

Answer (score 0):

The service account configured for the build service needs the rights. The TFS service and the build service may or may not be configured to run under the same account. Your personal account is not part of this equation.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN outlines the permissions required for each service account here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253149(v=vs.120).aspx Look at the entry for *TFSBuild*
The setup is also outlined in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181712(v=vs.120).aspx and explains how to pick what type of account you should choose when setting up your build server